# Ordered Binary Tree insert

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree

I have a problems in this code below, it's a part of a program for ordered binary trees. The problem is that when I enter numbers in the input, some elements are just lost and it happens all the times. I looked at the code and can't figure out why that happens. Can you help me out with this? Thanks.

```
void insert_ord(int number, struct treenode *currentNode){
   if(currentNode->flag == 0){
      currentNode->number = number;
      currentNode->flag = 1;                  
   }
   else{
      if(number <= currentNode->number){
         if(currentNode->left != NULL) insert_ord(number, currentNode->left);
         else {
            struct treenode *store = (struct treenode *)malloc(sizeof(struct treenode));
            currentNode->left = store;
            store->number = number;
            store->left = store->right = NULL;
            store->prev = currentNode;
         }
      }
      if(number > currentNode->number){
         if(currentNode->right != NULL) insert_ord(number, currentNode->right);
         else {
            struct treenode *store = (struct treenode *)malloc(sizeof(struct treenode));
            currentNode->right = store;
            store->number = number;
            store->left = store->right = NULL;
            store->prev = currentNode;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: aren't all binary trees ordered?

Comment: Yes they are, what do you mean?

Comment: "I have a problems in this code below, it's a part of a program for ordered binary trees." - the 'ordered' part is superfluous

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: no, a binary heap is not ordered in the sense I think you mean.  You can also use a binary tree as a "concatenation structure", where the values at the vertices are not ordered in any way.

Comment: @Mitch: sorry, I assumed from your question you were assuming binary trees to be totally ordered.  A heap is partially ordered and a concatenation tree is unordered.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't setting `store->flag` for the newly inserted nodes.  Presumably it should be set to 1.

You should also restructure your code so that the new node creation isn't duplicated - the easiest way to do this with your current code is to separate that out into a new function:

```
struct treenode *new_node(struct treenode *parent, int number)
{
    struct treenode *store = malloc(sizeof(struct treenode));

    if (store) {
        store->number = number;
        store->left = store->right = NULL;
        store->prev = parent;
        store->flag = 1;
    }

    return store;
}
```

Then your insertion code just becomes:

```
if (currentNode->left)
    insert_ord(number, currentNode->left);
else
    currentNode->left = new_node(currentNode, number);
```

(and similar for the right node).

Answer (score 0):

malloc returns uninitialised memory and you are not intialising the flag field of your malloced structures.

Comment: isn't this essentially what @Caf posted some 13 minutes earlier?

Comment: @Mitch, pretty much.  I didn't see Caf's reply when I hit submit.